# How can I get emacs 24.* under windows to autocomplete paths in shell buffers using “\” instead of “/”?

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, autocomplete

See [How can I get emacs under windows to autocomplete paths in shell buffers using "\" instead of "/"?](https://superuser.com/questions/258683/)

I use emacs on windows 7, when calling M-x shell, emacs opens a DOS-Shell. The prompt displays current directory using backslashes "\".

Wenn I type a path, say "C:\Te" and press [TAB] for completion, emacs completes the path to "C:/Temp/". This is ok for wirking inside emacs, but not for calling DOS-Commands or executing binaries or batch files in DOS.

Example: Command C:/Temp/a.bat fails. C:\Temp\a.bat executes fine.

The situation in emacs 24.* seems to be even worse. I thought I'd be an experienced emacs user but couldn't find a way to apply the patch named above to emacs 24.*. comint mode seems to have changed a lot.

Comment: 1. Perhaps give an example of the behavior you expect vs what you see. 2. Just why do you want to use `\ ` as a directory separator in this context?  Is it, e.g., because you have yanked a Windows-style "path" that has such separators? If not, why not just use `/` as the separator, as in the rest of Emacs?

Comment: @Drew The Windows command shell uses forward slash to introduce options, so paths containing it aren't properly interpreted.

Comment: @AaronMiller -- Oh, right; silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hack. It seems to work in emacs 24.5:

```
(defun win-file-name-completion-advice (res)
  (if (stringp res) (replace-regexp-in-string "/" "\\\\" res) res))
(advice-add 'comint-completion-file-name-table
            :filter-return #'win-file-name-completion-advice)

(defun win-command-completion-advice ()
  (let ((filename (comint-match-partial-filename)))
    (and filename (not (string-match "\\\\" filename)))))
(advice-add 'shell-command-completion
            :before-while #'win-command-completion-advice)
```

Answer (score -1):

[Topic 258683](https://superuser.com/questions/258683) descripes an appropriate solution:

- in file `~\.emacs`
- add line `(setq comint-completion-addsuffix (quote ("\\" . " ")))`

Comment: Actually, no. It explicitly says its working well only for emacs 22. This question was for emacs 24.